# Single object in view model base not updated in UI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have a view model that uses ViewModelBase from the MVVMLight framework. as follows

```
public class WorkDayViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IWorkDayServiceAgent _workDayServiceAgent;
    private WorkDay _workDay;

    public WorkDay WorkDay
    {
        get { return _workDay; }
        set
        {
            //_workDay = value;
            //RaisePropertyChanged();
            Set(() => WorkDay, ref _workDay, value);
        }
    }

    public WorkDayViewModel(IWorkDayServiceAgent workDayServiceAgent)
    {
        _workDayServiceAgent = workDayServiceAgent;
    }

    public async void LoadWorkDay(Date date)
    {
        WorkDay = await _workDayServiceAgent.GetWorkDay(date);
    }

    public void LoadWorkDay(WorkDay workDay)
    {
        _workDay = workDay;
    }

}
```

I have WorkDay bound to a WindowsPhonePage using the DataContext attribute.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...>
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <viewModel:WorkDayViewModel></viewModel:WorkDayViewModel>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>

    ...

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        ...

                <!-- current total -->
                <TextBlock 
                    Text="{Binding Path=WorkDay.Duration}" 
                </TextBlock>
        ...

            </Grid>


        ...
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

In the OnNavigatedTo method in code-behind I'm setting the data context to the first item when the dialog is shown.

```
workDayViewModel.WorkDay = (WorkDay) NavigationObjectCache.Get();
```

However, I have a button on that page to switch to another WorkDay for which I am using the following line in code-behind (from within the button event handler).

```
new ViewModelLocator().WorkDayViewModel.LoadWorkDay(previousDate);
```

This should actually trigger an update on WorkDay in the ViewModel and therefore an update on the UI. I used RaisePropertyChanged and the custom Set() methdo as you can see in hte code above but still nothing happens on the page. I.e. the workday does not change. Using the debugge I saw taht WorkDay is definitely update as expected.

So the question is: Why is the UI not updated allthough I change WorkDay in the view model which is bound to the UI using the data context.

Here is my ViewModelLocator. I'm using a static constructor so each view model is registered only once.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public WorkDayViewModel WorkDayViewModel
    {
        get { return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<WorkDayViewModel>(); }
    }

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        // services
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IWorkDayServiceAgent, MockWorkDayServiceAgent>();

        // view models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<WorkDayViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm using MVVMLight.

Comment: What is your implementation of "ViewModelLocator"?  I just wonder if you aren't creating a new instance of "WorkDayViewModel", rather that using the existing one that the page owns.

Comment: I added the view model locator to the description above. I think WorkDayViewModel is just created once because of the static constructor, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Xaml use the locator to get the data context:

```
DataContext="{Binding ViewModelName, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Also, you should have a parameterless ctor in your viewmodel.

And one more: 
To get a reference to the view model in the view code behind:

```
var vm = DataContext as ViewModelName;
```

Comment: This is exactly what was missing. I had to set the DataContext to the view model locator instead of the view model itself. It worked in the designer so I wasn't curious. What I had to change now is to add my designtime test data (which I had in my parameterless ctor before) to the ctor with the IWorkDayServiceAgent parameter. I can't use a parameterless ctor here because I'm using the services to access the data platform independently.